# pagination in function based view shows all objects

Tags: django, pagination

I have function based view and my pagination won't work properly. I see all objects in a single page, which is a problem, but page numbers are displayed correctly, which is a good thing.

my views.py looks like this:

```
def myview(request):
    qs = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefecth('something', something, something))

    paginator = Paginator(qs, 200)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {'qs': qs, 'page_obj': page_obj}
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

Below is mytemplate.html snippet. I literally used this example from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function)

```
{% for q in qs %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ q.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ q.phone }}</td>
  <td>{{ q.blah }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
      Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
  </span>
</div>
```

I hope someone can shed some light on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you *render* everything, where do you loop over the items to render these in the template?.

Comment: Hi again. I edited my post. Could you check it out again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `page_obj` (the `Page` object), not the queryset:

```
{% for q in page_obj %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ q.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ q.phone }}</td>
  <td>{{ q.blah }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In Django `QuerySet`s are (more or less) immutable, so that means that paginating, will *not* alter the queryset itself. The `Page` object makes a modified version of the queryset that is sliced according to the pages. By iterating over the page object, you thus iterate over a modified queryset.